# Who am I ??? - 3.0

Tags: knowledge, visual, rebus

From the pictures below, can you find my name ?

[image]

HINT 1

> Control

HINT 2

> All the pictures represent actions. Then control + __________ = action ?

Comment: Poor Mac users. Not only do they have to deal with bucketloads of software that isn't compatible with their systems, now they have to deal with incompatible *puzzles* too.

Comment: Did you mean **incompatible** ?

Comment: Whoops. fixed. (How'd that happen!?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are

> [Uvc](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60008/uvc)

Explanation

> Each of the images represents a computing action which results from pressing a combination of keys of the form "Ctrl + ___" together (as suggested by the hints): 
>  **First image:** Underline = Ctrl + **U** 
>  **Second image:** Paste = Ctrl + **V** 
>  **Third image:** Copy = Ctrl + **C** 
>  Combining the added letters gives the name of the user.